# Determine Appropriate Parent Div Height For Use With jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, database, resize, height, accordion

I'm generating a ladder system which is utilizing the jQuery Accordion function to render sections of the data expandable.  The problem I'm encountering is that when I click a header to make the content area drop down/unfurl, it resizes the page (and therefore the scrollbar to the right).

I'd like some way to programatically determine the height of the content I'm generating.  The data inside the accordion's content area is pulled from a database, and there's no way to know precisely how large it will be in advance.

Essentially, what I'm trying to accomplish is for the parent `<div>` to be set to a certain height, allowing just enough room for the accordions to expand without resizing the page.

Any ideas?  I would be most gracious!

### Edit

---

Actually, come to think of it, the size of the data contained in the content area is limited to a maximum of 10 lines. What makes the size unpredictable is the number of content areas that will be appearing. Is there a way to return how many SQL results match my query and then set the parent wrapper/encapsulating  to a height matching that number?

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the size of the data contained in the content area is limited to a maximum of 10 lines.  What makes the size unpredictable is the number of content areas that will be appearing. Is there a way to return how many SQL results match my query and then set the parent wrapper/encapsulating `<div>` to a height matching that number?

Comment: I don't know if it would be a sollution, but if you define the maximum size and use the jQuery UI Slider to scroll the content?!

Comment: Or you can put it inside a div with fixed height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(*)`

Will return a number from SQL depending on what you ask it. For example

```
$q = query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM **DESIRED TABLE** WHERE ** CRITERIA IS WHAT YOU WANT**');

echo json_encode($q);
```

Javascript make an ajax call to the above query get the number and set it to a JS var.  Now you have a js var with the row count in it

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. I'll let you know how it turns out! Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery:

```
var parentheight = $('.div').height(); // Height of the div.
```

And then you can use that whereever you want.

Would this work for you?

Comment: No, sorry. I am not trying to determine the height of a div. I am trying to determine what to set its height to based on the criteria described above.